# asp textbox watermark color

Tags: html, asp.net, css

Is there a way to change the colour of the watermark text in an asp.net textbox (to say, grey) whilst having any user typed text in the box be black?

When I change the color in css it changes user input text too which I don not want.

I have my textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="GVBox" id="promotionVoucherTxtBox" 
runat="server" watermark="Promotional code">
</asp:TextBox><br />
```

And my css rule:

```
input[type="text"], 
input[type="password"] 
    {padding: 3px 5px;
     border:1px solid #D1D3D4;
     font-size:13px; 
     color:#878787
}
```

However as I mentioned this changes all the text, watermark or user input. I have looked online but can't find anything about styling watermarks.

Comment: Use [TextBoxWaterMark](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx) from `AjaxControlToolkit`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using **ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender**. Check out the following code.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TBWE3" runat="server"
                    TargetControlID="txt1"
                    WatermarkText="Email Address"
                    WatermarkCssClass="txtwatermark" />
```

Add following Style for the Extender.

```
<style type="text/css">
 .txtwatermark 
    {
        color:gray;
    }
    .txtwatermark:focus 
    {
        color:black;
    }
    </style>
```